# best way to run shell commands like "bin/magento c:f" by using cron job magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-cron, cronjobs

I want to run some shell commands like c:f , c:c etc by using cron.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can below code logic to run commands

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Process\PhpExecutableFinderFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder;
use Magento\Framework\Shell;
use Magento\Framework\Shell\CommandRenderer;
class CustomModel
{
    
    protected $_shell;

    /**
     * @var PhpExecutableFinder
     */
    private $phpExecutableFinder;
    
    public function __construct(
        Shell $_shell,
        PhpExecutableFinderFactory $phpExecutableFinderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_shell = new Shell(new CommandRenderer());
        $this->phpExecutableFinder = $phpExecutableFinderFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $command
     *
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function run($command = 'cache:flush')
    {
        $phpPath = $this->phpExecutableFinder->find() ?: 'php';

        $this->_shell->execute('%s %s %s', [$phpPath, BP . '/bin/magento', $command]);
    }
}
```

just add this logic to your cron instance

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager $cacheManager
) {
    $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
}

private function whereYouNeedToCleanCache()
{
    $this->cacheManager->flush($this->cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());

    // or this
    $this->cacheManager->clean($this->cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());
}
```

Comment: thanks or your answer, but i want to run shell commands other then cache like custom indexers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I run a checkup for elasticsearch. it may be usefull to you, let me know :)

I'm using linux.
**nano /etc/crontab**

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command    

30 * * * * root php /var/www/html/teststore/app/code/elasticsearch.php
```

This script will run every 30 minutes.

Inside the php file I do the following instructions.Basically I check if the elasticsearch node is online and if not I kickstart it. Let me know if you need any further assistance

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:9100");
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_error($ch)) 
{
    shell_exec('sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch');
    shell_exec('sudo systemctl start elasticsearch');
    shell_exec('sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch');
    shell_exec('sudo php /var/www/html/teststore/bin/magento indexer:reindex');    
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```